# Automatically execute a javascript line before starting the Firebug console

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, firebug

Usually, in the linux/unix terminal is possible to initialize the console with a predeterminated line of code. I'm using the javascript console with Firebug, and I asked if it is possible with the Firebug's javascript console (Some script maybe...).

**Edit 1:**

An example:

Initially, when I start Firebug's javascript console, the Jquery library cannot be used with `$`, because Jquery is a namespace in my project, so I have to program a line of code for using the terminal the simbol `$` as Jquery (something like `$=PROJECT.NAME.$`);

I want to obviate this line of code for each time I refresh Firefox.

Comment: Can I ask the reason why you would need to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to run some code in firebug console when it opens or to just show the code there for you to run?

Comment: Can you give an example of "initializing the console with a predetermined line of code"?  I have no idea what you're asking about.

Comment: I have published an example of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to reassign $ in the code, I'd suggest creating a bookmarklet to execute the re-assignment. You'll have to click the bookmarklet every time you open Firebug.

Name:
$ reassign

URL:
javascript:$=PROJECT.NAME.$

(A bookmarklet is created the same way you would create a bookmark, but instead of opening a webpage, it executes the javascript in the URL.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to found another solution better than this. I think a firebug plugin to include pre-commands could be more interesting.